# How to clone till specific commit

Tags: git, git-merge, git-submodules

I need to clone a repo till a specific commit to a branch in my repo and then .merge it 
With my repo
But my repo has submodules which gets missed up when I clone first then revert to the commit I need

Answer (score 1):

I got almost nothing of what you said, sorry about this. But if you want to fetch *a part* of an independent remote repository then merge it into your own project, you probably want to manually add your remote repository :

```
git remote add <nameyou'llgivetothisremote> <urltoremoterepository>
```

then use

```
git branch -avv
```

to see both your own local branches and the ones of the remote repository.

You'll then be able to browse remote branches, then cherry-pick everything that you need or rebase a branch to where you want it to be in your local project.

You may optionally dismiss the remote repository after this if no longer needed.

Comment: Sorry I will try to explain

Comment: I have a repo that Is not up todate with the online one

Comment: I want to update it till specific commit not to most recent one

Comment: The repo contains submodules

Comment: The fact that your repository contains submodules doesn't matter (except if you need to retrieve some material from a submodule to another one). If you want to re-synchronise a given branch UP TO a certain point, you may directly move the branch (using *checkout -B* ou *reset --hard*) but if you're not used with Git, first update everything that's related with your remote repository with `git remote update`. Then, do a `git checkout` onto the "specific commit" you're targeting, create a branch with `git branch <branchname>`, go back to your original branch with `git checkout <originalbranch>`…

Comment: … then merge the new one into the current one with `git merge --ff <branchname>`.

The true question, however, is why do you want to do that ?

There's 99% chances you're doing something wrong.

Comment: The proplem with submodules is that each commit points to specfic commit in the submodule

Comment: After I do these steps end up not knowing which version in the submodule I am using